# If many clients request the same resource do reverse proxy servers make new request each time?

Tags: rest, http, proxy, reverse-proxy

The scenario being when many different clients are requesting the same resource from a reverse proxy server, is the reverse proxy forwarding the client request (to the server with the resource) for each client request? If so is that by default or does it depend on the configuration (the request headers: etags, if-none-match, .ect) between the proxy and server with the resource. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This question might be more appropriate over in [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/). That being said, it highly depends on the reverse proxy setup. It's likely both the reverse-proxy software being used (there are many, many types, from nginx, to custom c++, to even Apache) as well as the configuration set for each. If you're trying to write a reverse proxy, syndicating requests to the resource is a tempting, but dangerous idea. It works very well for public, static pages, but you have to be careful not to open just one connection to, for example, facebook.com, and send the result to two different people (showing one of them the other's personal data). For that reason, it should only be attempted when the resource marks, through [appropriate headers](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/optimizing-content-efficiency/http-caching?hl=en) that it is safe to cache.